# How do I turn off a network interface without an impact on other interfaces

Tags: centos, network-interface, remote

I have a server with several network interfaces.

- I use NIC1 eth0 to connect remotely.
- NIC2 eht1 is used in another local network.
- NIC3 eth2 is used for the internet access. The internet access is not always enabled.

Whenever I disable/enable eth2 with ifup or ifdown I loose the remote access. Then I have to locally go to the server and restart NIC1 to get access again.

Does anyone know how to prevent this? How can I enable other nics without loosing remote access?

Thank you so for reading this!

Comment: eth3 or eth2? On your second paragraph? I think you should check and post here the routing table. Possibly packets are going on eth2 instead of eth0

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I just corrected it. I will post the routing table on monday. I just lost access again and have to drive in to the server...

Comment: Are you certain these are 3 different physical interfaces, with 3 cables attached? Could be a bridge or a virtual NIC that is actually using another NIC to connect.

Comment: Yes, I'm certain that is 3 physical interfaces with cables. I cabled that myself. I talked to some collegues and they said that it was a CentOS thing and maybe it has something to do with the network deamon... but that couldn't help me any further.